# How can I allow my friend to see my screen using a web browser without requiring installation of any app on their or my device?

Tags: chrome-for-android, screen, browser, screen-sharing

I am specifically not looking for an App. The reason is that I want to just be able to send a link to a friend without them having to download an app.

Also sharing part of the screen, for example a tab on a browser would be super useful!

If this is not possible please recite the source. I am curious mainly about the mainstream browsers(since they are usually already installed on most phones) - Chrome(and other Chromium browsers), Firefox, Safari(I know this is not Android), Samsung Internet. I would still also appreciate information on any other browser!

If you know anything about plans for the future of this feature if it does not exist I would also be interested in that!

Maybe there is there a website I can use to share my screen on Android or do phone browsers not support screen sharing? a really good example for this is [Screen Meet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projector.screenmeet) which really goes half way, but still requires the user which shares to download an app but not the users who view the screen sharing unlike Facebook Messenger and Skype which force both users to download an app and even register. A good example for The PC is [Kosmi](https://app.kosmi.io/lobby).

Comment: sorry @beeshyams It was not suggested when I wrote screen so I assumed the tag did not exist thanks for adding it! I'll delete the screen tag and take a look at the questions there, have you come across a similar question or comment about this? I have searched the internet and found nothing so far..

Comment: @Robert this is not true, there are many apps which share the screen, e.g.  [Screen Meet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projector.screenmeet), [Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca) and more

Answer (score 1):

The W3C spec that covers screen capture for the Media API:

https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-capture/

is in Working Draft and as of May 2020 does appear to have some support on Desktop browsers but is not supported by any of the main Mobile browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API

[image]